# CiviMail mailing has 0 intended recipients

Tags: civimail

I'm having precisely the same problem as a number of others have reported here: When I create a mailing, and add a group os users, I get a notification of no intended recipients, and when I succeed in sending the mail anyway, the report says no recipients. It is precisely the same situation as described here:

[CiviMail mailing sometimes has 0 intended recipients](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3181/civimail-mailing-sometimes-has-0-intended-recipients?rq=1)

However, I'm using CiviCRM on a Joomla 3.6.2-site, not Drupal (CiviCRM 4.7.10 - no extensions installed). I have the same situation where I seem to be able to send test-mailings manually. So I guess this might be something to do with access rights. But where and how do I check that in a Joomla-installation? I'd very much appreciate some help on this, as it is critical for our organization to be able to send these mailings...

Magnus Larsson